# adding implementation and header files

Tags: xcode4

Hi all i have created my code etc for the .h/.m that are all ready provided. But i would like to known how to add more because when i add a view controller to my storyboard. I can't have code in it i think what I'm looking for is called a second view controller .h/.m. I am creating a project in Xcode 4.2 and its a single view based application. I'm new to this but i think what i have said makes sense thanks for your time.

kind regards

[image: i wo]

Answer (score 2):

- open your project
- press `command+N` to open the new file dialog
- iOS > CocoaTouch
- Class = YOUR_CLASS_NAME
- Subclass of = SUBCLASS_TYPE (e.g. UIViewController)

etc.

Comment: when i do that i get the view controllers but when i go into editor i get no assistant results??

Comment: sounds like you may have not checked the checkbox to add to the target